# string.replace for Titanium webview

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, ampersand

I have tried the following to no avail

```
var clean = link.replace(/\&nbsp\; /gi,' ');
```

I have also tried without escaping both the & and ; and escaping only one but it doesn't work. I can replace just plain nbsp.
Is there any way to replace   with just ' '?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on this with some people over on the Appcelerator Q&A and the best answer I could come up with is a work around at best.

```
var clean = link.replace(/nbsp/g," ").replace(/\&/g,"").replace(/amp\;/g,"").replace(/\;/g,"");
```

For obvious reasons this won't work for everybody since it will wipe out all semicolons and ampersands but it worked for me. I'm perplexed as to why I can't get the entire `&nbsp;` replaced but for now I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace `&nbsp;` with an empty string containing space `' '` entirely, just use:

```
var clean = link.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');
```